# How to use curl url for authintecation to informeica

Tags: php

i've tried to several day to use the api of informedica in php but no way i can do it.
I could not understand that example they put on their website. I do not know where I would add my credentials for response and how to make curl.
can you please show me the way to get the authentication right.
this is what i tried to do but

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.infermedica.com/v2/info');
curl_setopt($ch,'app_id',$app_id); 
curl_setopt($ch,'app_key',$app_key); 

 $res = curl_exec($ch);
 print_r($res);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: what `app_id` and `app_key` are?

Comment: never mind, I've found the documentation [here](https://developer.infermedica.com/docs/authentication).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://developer.infermedica.com/docs/authentication), you will see that `app_id` and `app_key` are extra header to include in the request. To add them you can use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'app_id: '. $app_id,
    'app_key: '. $app_key
));
```

Comment: thanks for your help
I'm beginner at this so can you please help
I've tried to make another curl for the condition.
i found in the documentation that the url of condition return list of condition so after the authentication if i replaced the url with the condition of url should i get that list or should i add more attributes

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: If i want to get the symptoms list .. should i change only the url or should i add more parameters?

Comment: have you read the documentation? it's written [here](https://developer.infermedica.com/docs/api#!/symptoms/getAllSymptoms) (`https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms`)

Comment: I've read the documentation several time but i didn't know what these letters mean (-v -H -X)
from your code i guess -H for header but can you explain the rest.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html | `-X` to specify the request method, `-v` per "verbose (useful to debug), `-H` for custom header